# Generalised integral $\int_{\pi/2 }^{ \pi} \frac{x^{4/3}}{\sin^2x}dx$

Tags: calculus

How do I go about deciding whether the generalised integral
$\int_{\pi/2}^\pi \frac{x^{\frac{4}{3}}}{\sin^2x}dx$
is divergent or not? Thankful for any tips! I have tried comparing with $\frac{1}{(\pi-x)^2}$ but have been unsuccessful.

Comment: You forgot the dx…

Comment: Try the substitution $u = x-\pi$

Comment: @DougM Hi, thanks for the suggestion! Do you mean I should do the substitution directly in the integral? I tried that but it didn't work for me. I don't know how to proceed from ((u+pi)^(4/3))/(sin^2(u+pi))

Comment: $\sin (u+\pi) = -\sin u.$  After this substitution we now have a problem as $u$ approaches $0$ and you can compare to $\int_{-\frac {\pi}{2}}^0 \frac {(u+\pi)^\frac 43}{u^2}\ dx$